# Socket.io-client on recieving event running useEffect two times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-hooks, socket.io

I'm trying to build a chat application,

The issue is whenever I send a emit an message to socket.io at the same time I recieve the same message two times. I got same message console.log two times.

Now this is my Server.js (Using express & Socket.io)

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const cors = require("cors");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
app.use(cors());

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`User Connected: ${socket.id}`);

  socket.on("join_room", (data) => {
    socket.join(data);
    console.log(`User with ID: ${socket.id} joined room: ${data}`);
  });

  socket.on("send_message", (data) => {
    socket.to(data.room).emit("receive_message", data);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
console.log("User Disconnected", socket.id);
  });
});

server.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("SERVER RUNNING");
});
```

And this is my client's chat.js where I am sending prop of

```
const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3001");
```

below is component

In this Chat component.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Chat({ socket, username, room }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    return () => {
      socket.off("receive_message", (data) =>
        console.log(`receive_message off ${data}`)
      );
    };
  }, [socket]);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="John..."
        onChange={(event) => {
          console.log(event.target.value);
        }}
        onKeyPress={(event) => {
          if (event.key === "Enter") {
            socket.emit("send_message", {
              room: room,
              author: username,
              message: event.target.value,
            });
          }
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default Chat;
```

After opening second tab I see two console.logs popping up with the same message. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here or missing here?

I have tried removing React.StrictMode from index.js, it resolves the issue but I don't want to remove it. Also after shifting my react version from 18 to 17 it also resolves the issue, how I can tackle this issue in 18. Also I want to cover that issue in same chat.js component. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    return () => {
      socket.off("receive_message", (data) =>
        console.log(`receive_message off ${data}`)
      );
    };
  }, [socket]);
```

You are properly trying to remove a listener on the return, but the problem is that you are removing the wrong listener--you have to pass the exact same function that you want to remove (because you can have two listeners on an event). This means that when the second render occurs during safe mode, you have two listeners added to that event.

Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {

    const receiveMessage = (data) => {
      console.log(data)
    }

    socket.on("receive_message", receiveMessage);

    return () => {
      socket.off("receive_message", receiveMessage);
    };
  }, [socket]);
```

That will make sure that the right function is removed. If this works, please make sure to mark my answer!